# Connect existing computer to SBS domain

Tags: domain, windows-sbs

I am going to connect a few existing PC's to a new windows SBS server and domain.  They have programs installed like quicken and other standalone software.

When I join the domain, how much do I need to worry about those programs and the data that resides in them?

I have connected two new computers to them, with little or no worries, but I am a little nervous about an established PC and the effect of running the SBS domain wizard on it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain membership should have little to no impact on your installed applications, unless the server admin has published policies that install/remove software. at the worst, the user might have to manually run the software as a local user if the software supports multiuser security, integrates with the Windows user model, and has existing accounts linked to local PC accounts.

Comment: I would want them to still run it off of the local PC for a while.  Does it matter that they currently are not on a domain?  I do not have any policies that say to wipe the software on the PC first.

Comment: well, on a domain, you can opt to login to the domain user, or the local user. additionally you can Shift +Rclick on a icon and run it as a differant user, so you could be logged in to your domain users desktop, but run a single app as your local user. as chris Avis points out below, this may require you to merge account data.

Comment: I am thick, I swear.  Let me get this straight.  If the user has data in their my documents or anything associated with their user profile, it's possible any program using that data could open and look like it's gone.  I would need to manually migrate it to the new profile, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you add a machine to a domain, you will alter the profile paths for users. That is the most severe change that will occur (unless you have a bunch of Group Policies that will apply in the new domain).

The profile changes can be seen by looking in -

c:\users\

You will often see the following if you move a machine from domain to domain or workgroup to domain where there are users with the same logon name -

c:\users\USERNAME.DOMAINNAME

ie; There is a user with the logon name of JSMITH that used the machine in a WORKGROUP and then in a DOMAIN

c:\users\JSMITH
c:\users\JSMITH.DOMAINNAME

You can manually copy data from one profile path to another if you wish to populate things like Documents, favorites, desktop, etc.

Chris E. Avis
Technology Evangelist - Microsoft
@chrisavis
chrisavis.com